# Just a thought: "a lot of water" --> plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, premodifiers

Can we label the phrase "a lot of water" as the pluralized form of "water"?

"a lot of" = expresses that something has a large amount

plural = more than one in number

But since we still cannot count "a lot of water," is it appropriate to label this phrase as plural?

Comment: Hm, interesting. Well, I can tell you this much. **Water** is a mass noun, aka a non-count noun. Mass nouns are things that cannot be counted. Like smog. It makes no sense to speak of one smog, two smogs, three smogs, or four smogs. Smog is a mass noun. Other examples: dirt, smoke, rain, wisdom, silence, joy, clutter, cotton, paper, heat, acid, gold. Mass nouns are usually “non-individuated groups,” meaning they are (usually) uniform substances without distinct constituent parts, like gases, liquids, metals, and powders. They have no plural form.

Comment: *A lot* just means a large amount of something; it doesn't confer plurality. Water can be singular ("this water is cold") or plural ("these waters are full of sharks"). Water by itself is uncountable.

Comment: No. _Plural_ is a grammatical term, with purely grammatical consequences. It is not a logical or semantic one.

Answer (score 6):

"A lot of water" is used with a singular verb. That means it is not plural, and it is not appropriate to label it as plural.

Here are just some quotes from the Corpus of Contemporary American English for your convenience.

- > And you have a lot of water that **needs** to run off
- > ... the canals are lined only with gravel, and a lot of water **is** lost because it **soaks** into the ground
- > I know a lot of water **has** crossed under that bridge.
- > ... a big problem with people pouring a lot of water on their land that**'s** not really needed.
- > Well, it's a long time ago now, and a lot of water **has** flown under our collective bridges.
- > You neglected to mention a lot of water **goes** out by that evaporation.
- > I heard another sound, a weird gurgling as though a lot of water **was** surging up through a hole in the ground.
- > and in the meantime, a lot of water **has** gone over the dam.
- > I think people are going to be OK in terms — a lot of water **is** coming into the region tomorrow, so we should be OK with that.
- > A lot of water **has** flowed under the bridge since I moved over to the sports department...

These are just ten random examples, the Corpus has more. I was unable, however, to find a single quote with *a lot of water* getting singular agreement. Not even as a one-off typo. Not a one.

As a general note, *plural* does not mean "more than one in number". *Plural* means that it is actually treated as plural.

- There are countless situations in which *a number, a lot, a total, a variety* are treated as plural. And so they are plural then. There are also countless situations in which *a number, a lot, a total, a variety* are treated as singular. And so then they are singular.
- Similarly, the news *is* good, and billiards *is* fun, and so we're clearly not looking at plural.
- And then there's use–mention. "People *are* poor", but "people *is* six letters long".
- Or think of how zero *is* a small number, and −0.7 *is* smaller still, and yet it's *zero miles* and *−0.7 miles*. The phrases are plural even though both numbers are less than one, proving right there that your definition does not hold a lot of water.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation, RegDwigнt! I previously thought that plural is a technical term dealing with quantities and numbers. Thanks for shedding some light!

Comment: Attribution of quoted material? - http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4981/71783